# Python mapping two csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, dask

I have a **config file** (csv) :

```
Column name;Function;Args
Region;function1;arg1
Country;function2;arg1, arg2
email;function3;arg1
...
```

And i want to apply a specific **Function** from my config file to a specific column in my csv file (`fileIn` **large file** > **1GB**) using dask, pandas or standard csv:

```
Region;Country;name
Europe;Slovakia;Mark
Asia;china;Steeve
...
```

Is there a a clean way to iterate over the config file ?

```
df = pd.read_csv(fileIn, sep=';', low_memory=True, chunksize=1000000, error_bad_lines=False)

for chunk in df
    chunk['Region'] = chunk['Region'].apply(lambda x: MyClass.function1(args1))
    chunk['Country'] = chunk['Country'].apply(lambda x: MyClass.function2(arg1, arg2))
    chunk['email'] = chunk['email'].apply(lambda x: MyClass.function3(arg1))
    
    chunk['Region'].to_csv(fileOut, index=False, header=True, sep=';')
    ...
```

here is an example of one of my functions called in my config file :

```
def function1(value, replaceWith):
    text = re.sub(r'[^ ]', replaceWith, value)
    return text
```

Comment: You could use [`dask`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv) for dataframes that don't fit in memory.

Comment: You can map specific functions to columns when reading the csv using the converters parameter of the read_csv method https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html/

Comment: @IvanCalderon it work good with pandas but i have a large files, and  i have read alot of articles which show that dask is more fast than pandas.

Comment: @siraj It seems that dask do the heavy work for you, so you can deal with a dask dataframe almost as you will do with pandas dataframe. If you already installed dask check dd.read_csv to spot if it has the converter parameter https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/01-data-access.html#Tuning-read_csv

Comment: @IvanCalderon, yes this is what im trying to do :  `df = ddf.read_csv(fileIn,  names='Region', low_memory=False)
df = df.apply(function1(df, '*'), axis=1).compute()` . i get this error : `expected string or bytes-like object` because my `function1` take @ arguments : the first is row value  (string) and the seconde is '*'. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you share the function?

Comment: @IvanCalderon, yes here is one of my functions : `def function1(value, replaceWith):
 text = re.sub(r'[^ ]', replaceWith, value)
 return text`

Comment: @siraj Ok then it seems that some values of your dataframe are not strings. It seems to me that you are aplying the function to the hole dataframe instead of doing it to specific columns as you posted in your code. Try to read a few lines of your csv file and check the datatypes of your df with type(df['Region']) for example

Comment: @IvanCalderon `df = ddf.read_csv(fileIn,  names='Region', low_memory=False)` i read only `Region` column. with pandas its work good, but with dask i get this error : `expected string or bytes-like object`.  i think I applied incorrectly my function1 to Region column. Can you please tell me how i can orrectly apply a lambda function ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Why use `pandas` for this simple task? You can use standard `csv` module, iterate `fileIn` row by row and apply your functions as fit on the columns. (so you avoid to read the file into the memory first)

Comment: @AndrejKesely can you please add an example as answer for this question? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a dict with functions and apply it to the chunk dataframe on each iteration.

Here's some code, please see comments for explanations:

```
# set up functions, for example
# - f1 to uppercase
# - f2 to lowercase
# - f3 to reverse string
def f1(x):
    return x.upper()

def f2(x):
    return x.lower()

def f3(x):
    return x[::-1]

# set up dict mapping function name in config to a function
fns = {
    'function1': f1,
    'function2': f2,
    'function3': f3,
}

# read config and set dict mapping column to a function
# here using the following `config.csv`:
#   Column name;Function
#   Region;function1
#   Country;function2
#   name;function3
df_config = pd.read_csv('config.csv', sep=';')
col_fns = df_config.set_index('Column name')['Function'].map(fns).to_dict()

# read and process csv in chunks
fileIn = 'file.csv'
fileOut = 'out.csv'
chunkSize = 1

df = pd.read_csv(
    fileIn, sep=';', low_memory=True, chunksize=chunkSize, error_bad_lines=False)

for i, chunk in enumerate(df):
    chunk_processed = chunk.apply(col_fns) # apply functions
    chunk_processed.to_csv(
        fileOut, index=False, header=(i==0), sep=';', mode='w' if i==0 else 'a')

# read the first 100 lines of the processed csv to test
pd.read_csv(fileOut, sep=';', nrows=100)
```

Output:

```
   Region   Country    name
0  EUROPE  slovakia    kraM
1    ASIA     china  eveetS
```

P.S. You'll need to change `chunkSize` to something reasonable, of course, only using 1 here for testing, because the `inFile` only has 2 lines, and we should test with multiple chunks

---

**Update:** If the functions you need to apply have some parameters, you can create wrapper functions:

```
# set up functions
def f(x, replaceWith):
    return re.sub(r'[^ ]', replaceWith, x)

# set up dict mapping function name in config to a function
fns = {
    'function1': f,
    'function2': f,
    'function3': f,
}

# read config and set dict mapping column to a function
# here using the following `config.csv`:
#   Column name;Function;args
#   Region;function1;A
#   Country;function2;B
#   name;function3;C
df_config = pd.read_csv('config.csv', sep=';')
col_fns = {r['Column name']: lambda x: fns[r['Function']](x, r['args'])
           for _, r in df_config.iterrows()}

...

# making it output both raw and processed values:
for i, chunk in enumerate(df):
    chunk_processed = chunk.apply(col_fns) # apply functions
    chunk_out = pd.concat(
        [chunk, chunk_processed.add_suffix('_processed')], axis=1)
    chunk_out.to_csv(
        fileOut, index=False, header=(i==0), sep=';', mode='w' if i==0 else 'a')
```

Output:

```
   Region   Country    name Region_processed Country_processed name_processed
0  Europe  Slovakia    Mark           AAAAAA          BBBBBBBB           CCCC
1    Asia     china  Steeve             AAAA             BBBBB         CCCCCC
```

Comment: My functions contains more than one argument, how can I add arguments to my functions? Here is an function example : `def function1(value, replaceWith):
    text = re.sub(r'[^ ]', replaceWith, value)
    return text`

Comment: Is it the same `replaceWith` value for all records? If that's the case, just create a wrapper function that accepts single value `x`: `f = lambda x: function1(x, 'your replaceWith value')`

Comment: Added an example in my answer, see Update

Comment: Oh, right, missed that somehow, please see the Update, I've added concatenation of the original values to the processed

Comment: Thanks, yes  its work for me. is there a way to add function arguments to the configFile ? like adding a new column to config file ? `Column name;Function;args
Region;function1;'A'
Region;function2;arg1,arg2`

Comment: Sure, you can dynamically create these wrapper functions, for example with `col_fns = {r['Column name']: lambda x: fns[r['Function']](x, r['args']) for _, r in df_config.iterrows()}` (assuming `fns` is a dict mapping function names like `function1` to actual functions)

Comment: Can you please update your answer? because i get this error :  `KeyError: 'args' `

Comment: You probably need to add `args` column to your `config.csv`. I've updated the answer (the Update part)

Comment: i get this error : `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison` because i have more than 1 argument (check the configFile in my question)

Comment: I think the best way is to give a list as argument for `function1` : `def function1(value, listParams):
 if type(value) is str:
  text = re.sub(r'[^ ]', listParams[0], value)
  return text`

Comment: If you have `arg1, arg2` in the `args` column of your config file, it will be read as a string, not as a list. It will be passed to the function as a string. If you want, you can split this string into a list, for example with `'arg1, arg2'.split(', ')`, which would give you `['arg1', 'arg2']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231013/discussion-between-siraj-and-perl).